# Rerender layout on user interaction in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm just starting to learn about Cytoscape. It looks like all the demos on the site calculate their layouts when the page loads, then become static.
Much like this demo: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/.
After the graph settles, dragging a node will not make the graph recalculate its layout.

I'm wondering if there's an option to continuously calculate layout every time the user interacts with the graph. 
This graph shows the functionality I'm looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWEOKw.
After dragging a node, the graph recalculates its layout.

Removing `infinite: true` from layout options in above example doesn't seem to do anything. Does only the `cola` layout have the ability to recalculate layout on user interaction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that changing to `infinite: false` does remove the constant rerendering. So if you want rerendering on user interaction, set `infinite: true`. I assume a number of layouts, including cola, have this option.